# TextColor doesn't change in UI

Tags: maui

I have a label that I am changing his color according to the action
in the XAML

```xml
<Label                                
    x:Name="yuval_spot"     
    Text="עמוס ספוט"     
    TextColor="Black"                     
    FontSize="15"                         
    Padding="30,0"                        
    VerticalOptions="Center"/>
```

when I change the color after pressing a button it changes

```cs
private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var item = ((Button)sender).BindingContext.ToString();
        x10call(item); 
        yuval_spot.TextColor = Colors.Red;
    }
    catch { }
}
```

when I am changing the color in a different function (activated by a response from a server ) it doesn't change it

```cs
unit = "yuval_spot";
findstat(ResponseMessage, unit, ref com);
if (com == "on")
    yuval_spot.TextColor = Colors.Red;
else
    yuval_spot.TextColor = Colors.Gray;
```

looking at the Watch I can see that the color is changed

[image]

all the program is in the same file  "MainPage.xaml.cs"
under `public partial class MainPage : ContentPage`

add the "function defined and how is it called "
[image]

Comment: Where is that other function defined and how is it called (*"activated by a timer"* as you wrote)?

Comment: i can see that the program is getting to this function and changing the label text  this program is working in visual c#  i am trying to export it to MAUI

Comment: I add some information to the thread the function  is activated by a response from a server, not a timer (the timer sends the request)

Comment: Please don't show code as images. Also, the image isn't really helpful.

Comment: what information do you need? putting all the code? it is very long :-(

Comment: I'm asking for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which contains just the code that is relevant to the problem. This involves all the places where you set `yuval_spot.TextColor` including some of the surrounding code, ideally the method signature, the class it belongs to and the call. You can redact the code and remove all the irrelevant bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UI changes need to execute on the [main thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/main-thread)

```cs
MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
    yuval_spot.TextColor = Colors.Gray;
});
```

Comment: tnx, this solves it . The correct syntax is    "MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>"  but the same idea :-)

Answer (score -1):

I think that the UI is not refreshing becouse you are not raising a property changed , the easiest way to achieve that would be to bind the color to a viewmodel attribute

```cs
public class MainPageViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private Color _textColor;

    public Color TextColor
    {
        get => _textColor;
        set
        {
            if (_textColor == value)
                return;
            _textColor = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    { 
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

```xml
<Label                                
    x:Name="yuval_spot"     
    Text="עמוס ספוט"     
    TextColor="{Bind TextColor}"                     
    FontSize="15"                         
    Padding="30,0"                        
    VerticalOptions="Center"/>
```

Comment: While this should work, the OP isn't using any data binding or ViewModels. The `TextColor` property is set directly on the Label and that should normally update the color as expected, raising a `PropertyChanged` event shouldn't be necessary.